# res.cookie set the token on the localhost but not on server

Tags: node.js, cookies, token, backend

```html
function setTokenCookie(res, token) {
    console.log(token,"pop")
    // create cookie with refresh token that expires in 7 days
    const cookieOptions = {
        httpOnly: true,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7*24*60*60*1000)
    };
    res.cookie('refreshToken', token, cookieOptions);
}
```

when try to set cookie on the localhost it works perfectly but i upload my backend on the server that time it not set the cookie

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your backend's domain is different from your frontend, hence more option is still required to ensure cookie will be set.

```
function setTokenCookie(res, token) {
  console.log(token,"pop")
  // create cookie with refresh token that expires in 7 days
  const cookieOptions = {
      httpOnly: true,
      expires: new Date(Date.now() + 7*24*60*60*1000),
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
      sameSite: 'lax',
      path: '/'
  };
  res.cookie('refreshToken', token, cookieOptions);
}
```

if you backend domain is thesame as frontend then you may set the sameSite attribute to "strict". secure attribute should also be set to true when you're not in development mode.

If you'd ask my personal preference, i would set cookie using the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) library like this:

```
 res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookie.serialize("refreshToken", token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development',
        sameSite: 'strict',
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        path: '/'
    }))
```

In addition:
after following the above configuration, you shouldn't forget to set the withCredential to "true" in your fetch/axios req option when making your fetch request to ensure set cookie is sent with the request.

Comment: i check the req.cookies it comes null from frontend but in frontend value is present this problem only occur on server only because of localhost it work perfectly  i am using react for frontend

Comment: set withCredential flag to true in your request option on the frontend, if it's not set to true it won't send your cookies along with the request, that's why the req.cookies is null

Comment: bro i check the code it's already credential:include  flag is added. but still error